# Jquery. Calling a function after .each loop with ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, each

I've been searching online for hours and I know that I probably have to do something with the deferred objects, but I can't get it done.

Firstly, here is my code:

```
$('#uploadButton').on('click', function () {
    //some preparation stuff (deleted)
    var panels = boxesContainer.find('.panel');
    var ajaxes = [];

    $.each(panels, function (index, panel) {
        //more preparation + declaration of variables

        function getIdAndPrepareData() {
            $.when(
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'url',
                data: {
                    'title': name
                }
            }))
                .done(function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                if (result.success) {
                    var id = result.id;
                } else {
                    getIdAndPrepareData();
                }

                console.log('Created Id: ' + id);

                $.each(panelForms, function (index, form) {
                    var filesInput = //again, prep and vars 

                    $.each($(filesInput)[0].files, function (index, file) {
                        var formData = new FormData();
                        formData.append('file', file);
                        //more stuff
                        ajaxes.push({
                            'formData': formData,
                            'file': file
                        });
                    });
                });

            }).fail(function () {
                getIdAndPrepareData();
            });
        }

        getIdAndPrepareData();

    });

    $.ajax().promise().done(function () {
        console.log('bla bla bla');
    });
});
```

So, basically, I am looping through certain DIV's (.panels) and creating a new database entity via ajax for them. Then I am preparing data to be sent to server via ajax, after all the loops complete. And I need to send this data after all the loops with ajax, because the next ajax calls (that I am planning to make after the iterating through .panels and preparing data) are going to create another entities that will be related with the entities created for .panel DIV's ( I push all this data to ajaxes array, and plan to use it leter on ).

I am using jQuerys deferred objects inside panels loop in order to get the newly created ID of the panel, and hold it in the ajaxes array. But I do not know how to execute any code after the panels loop.

I tried to make a promise (I am quite new to this technique) for all ajax calls at the end ( $.ajax().promise().done ), but id doesn't seem to work. Sometimes the console.log in the promise, fires at the end, sometimes at the beginning.

I am not an expert in jQuery and JS, so I would like to ask for some explanations how to work with asynchronous ajax calls inside loops and what should I do in this situation? I want to execute some code at the end, after all the data is prepared.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will get answers using arrays of promises and evaluating them using array evaluation against `$.when` etc, but there is a handy shortcut where you can chain `$.when` calls with only a slight overhead:

Pseudo code below:

```
var promise; // undefined is a resolved promise to $.when  
for (items in a loop){
    promise = $.when(promise, $.ajax({...});
}
promise.done(function(){
    // All done
});
```

### Notes:

- `$.ajax` returns a promise. That promise is to call you back on completion with the data or an error.
- `$.when` calls you back when a number of promises have completed (or when any fails)
- If you call `$.when` with an existing promise and a new promise you get back a third promise that will complete when both are done. These can be chained together in sequence.
- The downside of this shortcut is that the final data values passed to done are more complex that expected with normal evaluation of an array of promises against `done`.

*I use this technique, in preference to arrays of promises, when I just need to know overall completion and not all the individual data/results. It makes for far simpler code and the overhead of the extra promises is minimal. It also works great with sets of animations.*

Comment: Thank you. I still don't understand this technique fully, but I am going to try to implement it.

Comment: You will not find it referenced anywhere, but you will see examples of `.then()` calls being chained for sequential work. I came up with this after seeing the chained `then` and some experimentation. Hope it helps.